# C# Code Launches A Process, Redirects stdin/stdout, Subsequent ReadLine() From stdout Fails

Tags: c#, python, io-redirection

I have C# code that is launching a process that happens to be a python interpreter running a script.  The goal is to redirect stdin and stdout of that interpreter as a means of interprocess communication with the script.  The code is as follows:

```
        String py_path = @"C:\Anaconda3\python.exe";
        String script_path = @"<python script>";
        String working_dir = @"<directory of python script>";
        // Create new process start info 
        ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(py_path); 
        // redirect standard in and out 
        myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
        myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true; 
        myProcessStartInfo.Arguments = script_path;
        myProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = working_dir;
        Process myProcess = new Process(); 

        // assign start information to the process 
        myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;

        // start process
        myProcess.Start();

        //read one line from stdout
        StreamReader myStreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput; 
        String return_value_1 = myStreamReader.ReadLine();

        if(return_value1 == null)
            Print("Null return value");
        else
            Print(return_value1);
```

This code fails (`return_value1` is `null`) even though the first thing the python script does is printing a line on stdout.

However, if I comment out the redirection of standard input (which is otherwise untouched in this example) as follows:

```
        String py_path = @"C:\Anaconda3\python.exe";
        String script_path = @"<python script>";
        String working_dir = @"<directory of python script>";
        // Create new process start info 
        ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(py_path); 
        // redirect standard in and out 
        myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
        myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        //myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true; 
        myProcessStartInfo.Arguments = script_path;
        myProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = working_dir;
        Process myProcess = new Process(); 

        // assign start information to the process 
        myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;

        // start process
        myProcess.Start();

        //read one line from stdout
        StreamReader myStreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput; 
        String return_value_1 = myStreamReader.ReadLine();

        if(return_value1 == null)
            Print("Null return value");
        else
            Print(return_value1);
```

Then the code prints the first line the python script writes to its stdout, as I would expect.

Clearly somehow redirecting stdin is causing that `ReadLine()` of the redirected stdout to return null, but I do not understand the interaction.

There is a possibility that the deadlock problem described here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx
is somehow involved, but I don't immediately see how that could be the case.

Answer (score 0):

For your first example use 
`myProcess.StandardInput.Close();` after `myProcess.Start()`. You should send all the input before get output.

Although if you want output and errors from StandardError

```
string py_path = @"C:\Anaconda3\python.exe";
string script_path = @"<python script>";
string working_dir = @"<directory of python script>";
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(py_path)
{
    Arguments = script_path,
    WorkingDirectory = working_dir,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true
};
var process = new Process { StartInfo = processStartInfo };
process.Start();
process.StandardInput.Close(); 

var stdOut = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
var stdErr = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => process.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
process.WaitForExit();
var output = stdOut.Result;
var error = stdErr.Result
```

I used Task because if the stdout or stderr have lot of data the buffer might be full and the app will hang

I added also a way to get out/error asynchronously and you can write to input

```
string py_path = @"C:\Anaconda3\python.exe";
string script_path = @"<python script>";
string working_dir = @"<directory of python script>";
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(py_path)
{
    Arguments = script_path,
    WorkingDirectory = working_dir,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
};
var process = new Process { StartInfo = processStartInfo };

var outputBuffer = new StringBuilder();
var errorBuffer = new StringBuilder();
process.OutputDataReceived += (s, ea) => outputBuffer.AppendLine(ea.Data);
process.ErrorDataReceived += (s, ea) => errorBuffer.AppendLine(ea.Data);
process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();

process.StandardInput.WriteLine();

// from now on can write what ever to StandardInput and data will be into output
// and error buffer. Sometimes might want synchronization between read and write 
// also might want to empty buffers
```

Comment: Ideally I would be able to intermix input and output even though my initial example didn't show it.  Is this not possible for some reason?

Comment: Maybe a better way to phrase it is this: it appears that you're suggesting stdin has to be closed in order to read stdout.  That seems to defeat the purpose of stdin/stdout - for example when a program is part of a series of a unix-style pipe or even just connected to the console aren't they both open at the same time?

Comment: Maybe instead of close the Input you could just process.StandardInput.WriteLine();

Comment: I added a new snippet where you can intermix input/output

Comment: OK, I'll give it a try.  Thanks for putting in so much effort.  I worked around my immediate problem by running one direction of communication through a file, and for this application that worked OK but it's messy and slower I'm sure.